# Gamma representation of certain sequence

Tags: summation, gamma-function, products

I'm trying to find a gamma rep for $ 15 \cdot 13 \cdot 11 \cdot 9 \cdot 7 \cdot ... $

---

Steps so far:

It's a simple sequence of $ n \cdot (n-2) \cdot (n-4) \cdot (n-6) \cdot (n-8)... $ and so on.

Allegedly I am supposed to find an equivalent expression using factorials and powers of 2

$$= n\cdot(n-2(1)) \cdot (n-2(2)) \cdot (n-2(3)) \cdot (n-2(4)) \cdot ...      $$
I know that $$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$$  and  $$   n\Gamma(n) = n \cdot (n-1)!  $$

I've fiddled and monkeyed with this for a while now.  How in the world the above sequence translates into a gamma/factorial equivalent I have no idea.

---

Update:  I'm not even sure how powers of two are involved.

It seems like a simpler expression can be constructed, but I believe the point of the exercise is to transform it into gamma functions, which is where I start drawing a blank.

Comment: Notice that it is $15!$ or $16!$ divided by the product of several even numbers

Comment: 15!! (long live the semi-factorial!)

Comment: I see that but how do you prove it?  Working with what Henry said: $$ \frac {n!}{(n-1) \cdot (n-3) \cdot (n-5)...} $$ where $ n = 15$.  Why can't I figure this out?  It seems so easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)\cdots1
&=\frac{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdots1}{2n(2n-2)(2n-4)\cdots2}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{2^n\Gamma(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(2n)}{2^{n-1}\Gamma(n)}\\
\end{align}
$$
This is also known as $(2n-1)!!$ which is the [Double Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked an answer:

$$ S = 15 \cdot 13 \cdot 11 \cdot ...$$

$$ \rightarrow S = \frac {15!}{(n-1)\cdot(n-3)\cdot(n-5)\cdot(n-7)\cdot...}$$

Looking at Denominator: $$ (n-1)\cdot(n-3)\cdot(n-5)\cdot(n-7)\cdot(n-9)\cdot(n-11)\cdot(n-13)     $$  $$  =(n-2z+1)  $$

This was the error on my part, not noticing the $z$ term

$$\rightarrow  S=\lim_{n\to15}\frac{n!}{(n-2z+1)}  $$

Still working on how to transform into Gamma functions...